# Automatic ImageSliding using viewPager

Tags: android

I am trying to implement the automatic image slide using View Pager.  I used handler to slide the images one after another for certain interval (like 10 seconds).  This is my code please tell me where i am doing wrong.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    CustomPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    static int i=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);


        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < mCustomPagerAdapter.getCount()-1; i++) {
                    final int value = i;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(value, true);
                            mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();

//        mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);

    }

    }

     class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{


        Context mContext;
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

        int[] mResources = {
                R.drawable.splash0,
                R.drawable.splash1,
                R.drawable.splash2,
                R.drawable.splash3,
                R.drawable.splash0,
                R.drawable.splash2
        };
        public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {

            mContext = context;
            mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mResources.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
              return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
        }

         @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

                container.addView(itemView);

                return itemView;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Thread.sleep() has ms arguments, so if you want 10 seconds, you have to put 10000 in this method

Comment: but images are not getting swipe

Comment: Can you confirm `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(value, true);` is executed?

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (index < mCustomPagerAdapter.getCount()) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index, true);
                            index++;
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    this.cancel();
                }
            }

        }, 10000, 10000);
```

Comment: You do not need new thread. Do not set adapter often, setting it once will be sufficient.

Comment: @ Anitha  i am getting Fatal Exception: timer 0 .I initialize the timer but still it gives the same error where i am setting the mView Pager.set Current Item (index , true);

Comment: Just that we were not updating index, it lead to infinite loop! Update the index as in the post and try. And index should be global variable.!

Comment: still i am getting error in the method   public Object instantiate Item(View Group container, int position){ container.add View(item View);
}

Comment: Remove that line alone.  No need to add to the parent.  Anyways you are returning the view right.

Comment: If i remove the addview the image shouldnot be visible.I removed that one but images is not visible and after 10 sec same error is coming.

Comment: Check my updated code! It works and I have checked it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works great

```
mIntroPagerAdapter = new mIntroPagerAdapter(this);
mIntroViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mIntroViewPager.setAdapter(mIntroPagerAdapter );   

static int i=0;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    void setImageMove()
    {
        handler.post(ViewPagerVisibleScroll);
    }

        Runnable ViewPagerVisibleScroll= new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if(i <= mIntroPagerAdapter.getCount()-1)
                        {
                            mIntroViewPager.setCurrentItem(i, true);
                            handler.postDelayed( ViewPagerVisibleScroll, 10000);
                            i++;

                        }

                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Autoscroll ViewPager](https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager) library.

If you need just sliding images then [AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) might be more convenient. I've used it and it does the job perfectly.

Actually, you can get the idea how to implement [AutoScrollViewPager:scrollOnce()](https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager/blob/master/src/cn/trinea/android/view/autoscrollviewpager/AutoScrollViewPager.java#L155) sliding from those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

> Call this method pageSwitcher

```
int page = 0;
pageSwitcher(10); 10 Seconds
public void pageSwitcher(int seconds) 
{
    timer = new Timer(); // At this line a new Thread will be created
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 0, seconds * 1000); 
    // delay in milliseconds
}

class RemindTask extends TimerTask 
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                if (page > mResources .size()-1) 
                { 
                    page=0;
                } 
                else
                {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(page++,true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}